# What to make of recruiters reply after interview

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, new-job, recruitment, feedback

I went through a series of interviews and company's HR/recruiter was very generous to provide feedback after each interview. Feedback was really positive and they were interested (I applied through a referral). After 3rd and final interview I got a call saying the feedback is really good, i am a great fit, they are interested, but there was someone who started interview process before me and the position is filled. They will talk to leadership team to create another position hopefully and get to me next week because they really liked me as a candidate. I am not sure how much to believe this. They mentioned my salary twice in this call and were confirming you are looking for x right? I said yes so i just suspect maybe the salary is too high or what can be the reason? any advice?

Comment: If they really want you but your desired salary is too high, they might hazard an offer of employment but with a lower salary. It can happen.

Answer (score 7):

No particular reason not to take what they say at face value - asking about the salary sounds to me like they want to check how much budget they'd have to find for the potential new position.

I wouldn't be pinning any real hopes on it - just carry on with your normal job search process and if they get back to you great, if not then you've not lost anything.

Comment: thanks a lot - I just didn't get the reason for carrying on with interviews if the position was filled or maybe the position was filled after they setup my last interview and because of earlier positive feedback they still wanted to interview me and see if they can fit me in somewhere

Comment: @MarkG I'd suspect the position wasn't confirmed filled until after your last interview or at the least after it was too late to cancel it. It's also possible that they wanted to interview you anyway if they had they had the potential alt position in mind but the former is the most likely IMO

Comment: @MarkG, filling the position completed until the other candidate accepted the offer, until they have an accepted offer, the need to keep the interviewing process going.  They could have easily extended the offer to the other candidate and been waiting a few days for a response while they were doing your last interview.